# Pass a string into a background method

Tags: android, callback, parse-platform

Summary of problem: I am downloading a bunch of images using background methods and then saving the images to access them later. My problem is that I need a way to associate each saved image with a string that I already determined before the call to the background method. Using a getter and setter won't work because the string may change before each callback method is called. Is the only way to subclass the getDataInBackgroundMethod? Hopefully their is an easier way :) The actual code works fine apart from passing in the variable.

```
  //.... Continued from previous code....

    //Iterate through the items of an array that has previously been returned

    Word wordObject = (Word) itr.next();

    //Get the title to store the picture under in local database.

    String stringIwouldLikeToPassIn =  wordObject.getTitle();

    //Parse file is the object responsible for holding the pictures

    ParseFile file = wordObject.getParseFile("Pics");

    file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

    //Get the actual data for the pictures and then store them in 
    //local memory in byte form. 

    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {

    try {
    //*** TO DO: I want to have the tempString be passed in so that    
    //*** I can save the file with the name of the object that was originally called

    ---> String stringFromCallBack = stringIwouldLikeToPassIn <---------
    //This doesn't work as you can't pass an extra paramater into the call back...

    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(stringFromBeforeCallBack, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    fos.write(data);
                                    fos.close();

                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                              // something went wrong
                            }
                          }
                        });

                    //Pin each word in the background so we can use the objects
                    wordObject.pinInBackground(null);

                    //Add each question round to the local relations
                    relation.add(wordObject);

                    //Write each word object to title
                    Log.d(DEBUG, wordObject.getTitle());

                  }

                  //After adding the relative array of question objects then we save
                  user.pinInBackground(null);
                  user.saveEventually();



            }



        });

//      }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to `GetDataCallback`, and pass your string into the constructor when you create your `GetDataCallback` instance. To do this, you will need to declare `stringIwouldLikeToPassIn` as `final`.